# Convert UTF-16 to code-page and remove unicode text direction control characters?

Tags: winapi, unicode, codepages

### Short version

- Given:         `1/16/2006 2∶30∶11 ᴘᴍ`
- How to get: `1/16/2006 2:30:11 PM`
- rather than: `?1/?16/?2006 ??2:30:11 ??`

### Background

I have an example Unicode (UTF-16) encoded string:

```
U+200e U+0031 U+002f U+200e U+0031 U+0036 U+002f U+200e U+0032 U+0030 U+0030 U+0036 U+0020 U+200f U+200e U+0032 U+2236 U+0033 U+0030 U+2236 U+0031 U+0031 U+0020 U+1d18 U+1d0d
 [LTR]      1      /  [LTR]      1      6      /  [LTR]      2      0      0      6         [RTL]  [LTR]      2      ∶      3      0      ∶       1      1             ᴘ      ᴍ
```

In a slightly easier to read form is:

> <kbd>LTR</kbd>1/<kbd>LTR</kbd>16/<kbd>LTR</kbd>2006 <kbd>RTL</kbd><kbd>LTR</kbd>2∶30∶11 ᴘᴍ

The actual final text as you're supposed to see it is:

> [image]

I currently use the Windows function **WideCharToMultiByte** to convert the UTF-16 to the local code-page:

```
WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, 0, text, length, NULL, 0, NULL, NULL);
```

and when i do the text comes out as:

```
?1/?16/?2006 ??2:30:11 ??
```

I don't control the presence of the Unicode text direction markers; [it's a security thing.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20150506-00/?p=44924) But obviously when i'm converting the Unicode to (for example) ISO-8859-1, those characters are irrelevant, make no sense, and i would **hope** can be dropped.

Is there a Windows function (e.g. `FoldString`, `WideCharToMultiByte`) that can be instructed to drop these non-mappable non-printable character?

> 1/16/2006 2∶30∶11 ᴘᴍ

### That gets us close

If a function did that, dropped the non-printing characters that don't have a representation in the target code-page, we would get:

> 1/16/2006 2∶30∶11 ᴘᴍ

When converted to ISO-8859-1, it becomes:

> 1/16/2006 2?30?11 ??

That's because some of those characters don't map *exactly* into ISO-8859-1:

> 1/16/2006 2<kbd>U+2236</kbd>30<kbd>U+2236</kbd>11 <kbd>U+1d18</kbd><kbd>U+1d0d</kbd>
>
> 1/16/2006 2<kbd>RATIO</kbd>30<kbd>RATIO</kbd>11 <kbd>Small Capital P</kbd><kbd>Small Capital M</kbd>

But when you see them, it doesn't seem unreasonable that they could be *best-fit* mapped into:

- **Original**: `1/16/2006 2∶30∶11 ᴘᴍ`
- **Mapped**: `1/16/2006 2:30:11 PM`

### Is there a function that can do that?

I'm happy to suffer with:

- 1/16/2006 2?30?11 ??

But i really need to fix:

- ?1/?16/?2006 ??2:30:11 ??

### Unicode has the notion

Unicode already has the notion of what "fancy" character you can replace with what "normal" character.

- **U+00BA** <kbd>º</kbd> → <kbd><sup>o</sup></kbd> *([Masculine ordinal indicator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ba/index.htm))* → *(Small latin letter o, superscripted)*
- **U+FF0F** <kbd>／</kbd> → <kbd>/</kbd> *([Fullwidth solidus](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff0f/index.htm))* → *(solidus, wide)*
- **U+00BC** <kbd>¼</kbd> → <kbd>1/4</kbd> *([Vulgar fraction one quarter](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00bc/index.htm))*
- **U+2033**  <kbd>″</kbd> → <kbd>′′</kbd> *([Double prime](http://U+2033))*
- **U+FE64**: <kbd>﹤</kbd> → <kbd><</kbd>

I know these are *technically* for a [different purpose;](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/decomposition). But there is also the general notion of [a mapping list](https://unicode.org/Public/idna/11.0.0/IdnaMappingTable.txt) *(which again is for a different purpose)*.

Microsoft SQL Server, when being asked to insert a Unicode string into a non-unicode `varchar` column does an even better job:

[image]

Is there a mapping list for the purpose of unicode *best-fit*?

Because the reality is that it just makes a mess for users:

[image]

Comment: There is no Win32 API function to do what you are asking for. You need to manually strip out unwanted chars from the string, and replace unmapped chars as needed, before then passing the string to `WideCharToMultiByte()`. You are dealing with a very specific use case, so it should be fairly straight forward to do the modifications manually.